# Using Lambda Map function instead of iteration to populate Map

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Below code converts List of Strings where the key and value are separated by "." to type `Map<String, java.util.List<String>>`

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.util.List<String> l = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
        l.add("key1.value1");
        l.add("key1.value2");
        l.add("key2.value3");

        java.util.Map<String, java.util.List<String>> map = new java.util.HashMap<String, java.util.List<String>>();

        l.forEach(line -> {
            String[] sa = line.split("\\.");
            List<String> ls = map.get(sa[0]);
            if (ls == null) {
                List<String> initial = new ArrayList<String>();
                initial.add(sa[1]);
                map.put(sa[0], initial);
            } else {
                ls.add(sa[1]);
            }
        });

        for (Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            List<String> value = entry.getValue();
            System.out.println(key+","+StringUtils.join(value , ","));
        }
    }
```

Is there a better approach using java lambdas ? Possibly using map function ?

Note : StringUtils is part of commons-lang lib :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct stream version should use the `groupingBy` collector:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = l.stream().map(s -> s.split("\\."))
        .map(s -> s.length > 1 ? s : new String[] {s[0], ""})
        .collect(
             Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s[0], 
                 Collectors.mapping(s -> s[1], 
                     Collectors.toList())));
```

Also note that in Java-8 there's `String.join` method, so you don't need the `StringUtils` to print the result:

```
map.entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> e.getKey()+","+String.join(",", e.getValue()))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: thank you, if wanted to check just add an element to list if array size returned by s.split("\\.") is > 1 would this force me to use iteration ?

Comment: @blue-sky, if you want to filter out the incorrect arrays, you can just add a filter step. I edited the answer.

Comment: sorry, meant adding a default value if the length is 1, I could just map through the original list and if its length is 1 append an empty String ?

Comment: @blue-sky, yes, you can easily map, though you cannot append array in Java, you need to create a new array. Edited the answer again.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
l.stream()
 .map(s -> s.split("\\."))
 .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s[0], s -> s[1], (a, b) -> b));
```

The last function is a merge-function which tells it to just pick the last value if two keys are equal. Not providing this function will throw an `IllegalStateException` if there are duplicate keys.

If you need a map from Strings to a list of Strings with the same keys. You can use the `Collectors.groupingBy` method (as in Tagir Valeev's answer).

Comment: you would want to concat the two lists in the merge function though. else, value1 in the example is lost.

Comment: Yes, I just provided that function as an example. You can do whatever you want in it.